# Cannot add SQL file to Git repository?

Tags: sql, git, repository

I need to add a SQL file to my Git repository. For some reason Tower or Git on the command line does not see that I've added a new file whenever it ends in .sql.

I've tried creating an empty .sql and removed everything in .gitignore, but it still doesn't see it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Although this probably shouldn't matter, what OS is this on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably have a global gitignore set up. This page on GitHub https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files recommends that SQL files are included in a global git ignore.

Follow instruction on that page to set your own global rules.

Comment: That was the problem. THANKS!!